# Is there any way to map a table function with hibernate POJO?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have a database function which returns a table type.

Is there any way to map this function with my hibernate POJO?

Comment: What do you mean by "database function"? Is that a Java metod or a stored procedure?

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about?

Comment: In hibernate pojo we can annotate class with @table in that we can provide table name.. Instead can I provide a function name which returns a table I am using Oracle database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible in many ways. For me [@NamedNativeQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NamedNativeQuery.html) is the most elegant way. However, you can check [here](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/) and choose which way is the most convenient for you.